# Swift - didSet property not called from binding changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My problem:

I want to call a function when my customView clicked

So I use @State variable to observe the click action from my custom view. But the problem is **my value changed but didSet function not triggered**

My code:

**Main struct:**

```
   @State var buttonClicked : Bool = false {
        didSet{
          needToCallMyFunction() // not triggered 
        }
    }
```

**Custom struct:(for my customview)**

```
@Binding var isClicked : Bool

someview
.onTapGesture(perform: {
            print("custom clicked")
            isClicked.toggle()
        })
```

Comment: How you are initialising the custom class from main class ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Its struct. I use the one custom struct for customizeView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use instead in main view `.onChange(of:)` modifier, like

```
  SomeView()
    .onChange(of: buttonClicked) { _ in
       self.needToCallMyFunction()
    }
```

Update: variant for SwiftUI 1.0 / iOS 13+

```
import Combine   // needed to use Just

...

  SomeView()
    .onReceive(Just(buttonClicked)) { _ in
       self.needToCallMyFunction()
    }
```

Comment: Hi Asperi Both are not in same struct. StructA have one view (StructB) if I click from StructB -> I want to trigger StructA function

Comment: It does not matter, changing binding you change only state in reality, so use it in view having declared state.

Comment: onChange only available for 14 +.  My app supports from 13

Comment: See updated with variant for iOS 13 support.

Answer (score 0):

Asperi solution working fine.

But it have one bug in lower versions. It called multiple times

I found another solution

```
SomeView(buttonClicked: 
             Binding(get: { self.buttonClicked },
                     set: { self.buttonClicked = $0
                               print("your action here ")
                }))
```